Jetpack Compose: 'by viewModels()' vs 'viewModel<ViewModelName>()'
What's the difference here?
val myViewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()

versus
val myViewModel = viewModel<MyViewModel>()

How does the first way work? How does it know which ViewModel to initialize? From the type-annotation after the variable-name?

In Android development using Kotlin, there are two common ways to initialize ViewModels in ViewModel-backed fragments or activities: by viewModels() and viewModel() functions provided by Android Jetpack libraries.
by viewModels()

This approach is typically used with Kotlin property delegates.
It automatically initializes the ViewModel associated with the given fragment or activity and retains it across configuration changes.
The type of the ViewModel is inferred from the type of the property.
This method is concise and generally preferred for simplicity and brevity.

viewModel()

This approach is a function provided by the viewModel-ktx library in Android Jetpack.
You explicitly specify the type of the ViewModel you want to retrieve.
It allows for explicit specification of the ViewModel class.
Useful when you need to retrieve a ViewModel of a different type than the property type.


No idea, but I dislike the 'by viewModels'-way. I like programming, which is explicit and not this esoteric 'you got to know that somehow'-way. Such stuff makes one uncertain, when one doesn't program in the specific environment a lot every day.

The main difference is the context and framework they are intended for:

The first method
val myViewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()

(by viewModels()) is primarily used in traditional UI development
(Activities/Fragments with XML layouts),

while the second (viewModel()) is used within Jetpack Compose.
val myViewModel = viewModel<MyViewModel>()

You can read more here Android viewmodel
